# Wildcard automounts with systemd

Tags: nfs, systemd, fstab, autofs

I’m running jessie/sid with systemd 208 and try to convert the following wildcard autofs configuration to either an `/etc/fstab` or `.mount`/`.automount` definition.

```
$ cat /etc/auto.master
/home/* -fstype=nfs homeserver:/exp/home/&
```

(homeserver runs a Solaris with each subdirectory in `/exp/home/` being a separate share.)

Is there a way to emulate wildcard maps with systemd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose no. The .mount/.automount unit name has to be equal to the mount path, escaped with `systemd-escape --path`. And the only way in systemd to instantiate units is "template syntax" of a form `foo@bar.type`. Hence it is at least not possible to have a dynamically instantiated mount unit.

Just use autofs. systemd is not a replacement for everything.

Comment: Was having the problem that automount would hang on shutdown/reboot, so I was looking for a more integrated solution to hopefully avoid this.

Comment: @Debilski: This is a distinct problem. You can try to add ordering dependencies to `autofs.service` to prevent it from stopping too late. Maybe `After=network.target` helps. Just remember that you don't need to edit the whole unit file -- there are drop-in files exactly for that purpose ;)

Comment: Yes, that was my workaround in the end as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use systemd's [generator interface](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html). Basically, it creates service files on the fly upon start or reload.

We have a range of machines (called "dema" plus some number) in our cluster, which all export the same directory (their physical disk). I used the generator interface to create one *.mount* and one *.automount* file for each machine:

```
#!/bin/sh

svc_dir=/run/systemd/generator

for i in $(seq 1 99); do
    # this must match the mount path, / is converted to -
    unit_bn=cluster-dema$i
    cat << EOF > "${svc_dir}/${unit_bn}.automount"
[Unit]
Description=dema${i}s localdisks automount point
Documentation=file:///usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/dema-automount-generator
Before=remote-fs.target

[Automount]
Where=/cluster/dema$i
EOF

    cat << EOF > "${svc_dir}/${unit_bn}.mount"
[Unit]
Description=dema${i}s localdisks
Documentation=file:///usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/dema-automount-generator

[Mount]
What=dema$i:/localdisks
Where=/cluster/dema$i
Type=nfs
Options=rw,nosuid,nodev,hard,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,noauto,x-systemd.automount
EOF
    ln -s "../${unit_bn}.automount" "${svc_dir}/remote-fs.target.requires"
done
```

The script has to be placed into */usr/lib/systemd/system-generators* and executable. After putting it there, call *systemd daemon-reload* and you should find the units in */run/systemd/generator*. There are activated on next reboot and can be manually started, of course, by calling *systemd start oneofthenames.automount*.